# Is Gesture lock is secure enough for financial applications on android/Iphone devices

Tags: android, locking, gesture-recognition

We want to implement gesture lock for a financial based application on Android device. I would want to know if this mechanism is secure enough for this kind of aplication.  any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think that gesture lock isnt enough. Make a gesture in the screen leave a little mark of dirt that can look it with sun light (for example).

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution http://www.whispersys.com/screenlock.html